# '[07000] The executeUpdate method must not return a result set. ' in Datagrip

Tags: sql-server, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

When I modify the data directly in the table with an update trigger, there will be an error "[07000] The executeUpdate method must not return a result set.", but there is no such error when running `UPDATE Lab5.SaleOrderDetail SET Quantity = 3 WHERE OrderID = 7 AND ProductID = 74;`
in the query console, and the trigger works well.
[The [07000]error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKeNV.png)
The DDL of that table is

```sql
CREATE TABLE Lab5.SaleOrderDetail
(
    OrderID   int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT SaleOrderDetail_SaleOrder_OrderID_fk
            REFERENCES Lab5.SaleOrder,
    ProductID int NOT NULL,
    Quantity  int,
    UnitPrice int,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (OrderID, ProductID)
)
GO
```

The trigger is (I try to set coconut on, but the problem is still there)

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ChangeLastModified
    ON lab5.SaleOrderDetail
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE Lab5.SaleOrder
    SET LastModified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM lab5.SaleOrder
             INNER JOIN inserted i ON SaleOrder.OrderID = i.OrderID
END
```

[The tables in the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh9tu.png)
By the way, why is the trigger not listed in the list on the left

Comment: The posted code seems incomplete - I don't see SET NOCOUNT ON in the trigger.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning I tried to SET NOCOUNT ON, but the problem was still there.

Comment: It should be on the left part! Does sync help?

Comment: Hi @moscas, I tried to refresh the database (I think the sync should be automatic), but I still can't see the triggers. It's not the only problem for this table. I tried to add a new table with triggers, but the triggers weren't listed on the left.